# NextJS 14: server only library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sveltekit

Is there a way to define code in typescript files which are guaranteed to never be sent to the client? Some frameworks such as `svelte` provide these guarantees if a file is suffixed with `.server.ts`. See reference in docs [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#universal-vs-server).

Is there a similar thing in `NextJS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward, and a React solution compatible with any RSC implementation, not just specific to Next.js.

```bash
npm i server-only
```

Add the following at the beginning of your entry point:

```js
// src/index.ts

import "server-only";

// ...

// This code can't be imported from the client
```

The Next.js documentation says:

> To prevent this sort of unintended client usage of server code, we can use the `server-only` package to give other developers a build-time error if they ever accidentally import one of these modules into a Client Component.
>
> To use `server-only`, first install the package:
>
> ```bash
> npm install server-only
> ```
>
> Then import the package into any module that contains server-only code:
>
> ```js
> import 'server-only'
>
> export async function getData() {
>   const res = await fetch('https://external-service.com/data', {
>     headers: {
>       authorization: process.env.API_KEY,
>     },
>   })
>
>   return res.json()
> }
> Now, any Client Component that imports getData() will receive a build-time > error explaining that this module can only be used on the server.
>
> The corresponding package `client-only` can be used to mark modules that contain client-only code – for example, code that accesses the window object.
> ```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#keeping-server-only-code-out-of-the-client-environment

React is introducing two new experimental APIs for marking value or object as server only:

- [experimental_taintObjectReference](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_taintObjectReference)
- [experimental_taintUniqueValue](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_taintUniqueValue)

Comment: Have you looked into `server-only` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/server-only?activeTab=code)? All it does, it throws an error:

throw new Error(
  "This module cannot be imported from a Client Component module. " +
    "It should only be used from a Server Component."
);

Comment: I know. That's the way provided by the React core team

Comment: @Hardy The package works because it uses [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports). When importing the package from a `react-server` environment, the package resolves to an empty file, but when importing it elsewhere (i.e from `browser`), the package resolves to the file that contains that thrown error.